# Is there a way we can give dummy input to restkit?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am pretty new to the Restkit. I know how my restful response will be. Its not ready yet to get from the server side. Is there a way to give dummy input directly to restkit ?
We can give `json` text file as an input to `NSUrlConnection`, similarly how to do it here?

Comment: Maybe you can look for this kind of method : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788904/what-is-an-easy-way-to-stub-dummy-a-restful-web-service

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to do this is

```
- (RKObjectMappingResult*)mapResponseWithMappingProvider:(RKObjectMappingProvider*)mappingProvider toObject:(id)targetObject error:(NSError**)error {
```

in RKObjectLoader.m

where I optionally read a static json text file and replace the bodyAsString. If you look at

```
[self.URL description]
```

you can scan the URL and maybe read a test file based on the request url

Answer (score 0):

How about running a simple web server which will return any output you want in JSON format?
For example, when I need to prototype an app which will use RestKit, I create a simple ruby app using sinatra web framework (few lines of code) and start it locally, and point my RestKit based app to web app (http://www.sinatrarb.com)