# How do I test an android app against a web service

Tags: android, rest, testing

Without calling the webservice. Is there a testing framework/library to mock the responses? Use a fixture for responses?

Comment: Here's a simple way to use mock responses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8788904/what-is-an-easy-way-to-stub-dummy-a-restful-web-service/15243123#15243123

Answer (score 0):

You can test your webservices by downloading the `Advance Rest Client` plug-ins in your chrome browser.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. I want to test the android app. Although Advance Rest Client seems pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

There are several instrumentation frameworks such as [Mercury](http://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/tools/2012/03/16/mercury/documentation/white-paper/mercury-framework/) and [Instrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Instrumentation.html).

However, for actual network emulation your best bet would be to use a localhost server, for example with [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) which would let you run PHP locally and emulate the responses.